# Why did he start falling from the building?

Tags: plot-explanation, venom

Maybe a third of the way through [*Venom* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270797/), when Venom/Eddie was at the very top of the building that seemed to be where Anne's (Eddie's ex-girlfriend) office was, an airplane flew by and Venom/Eddie started falling.

According to a scene not too much later, it was revealed that Venom was only vulnerable to sounds between the frequency of 4000-6000 Hz (or something like that), and to fire.

IIRC though, neither of those were present at the time.

### ***So, what gives?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How a Symbiote Reacts**

Sounds within the 4000-6000 Hz frequency, make it shift or phase between human and symbiote uncontrollably and the host appears to fit while this happens.

This is shown 4 times throughout the film.

1. During the testing in the Life Lab
2. During the MRI
3. During the second MRI to extract the symbiote
4. During the final Battle (somehow Anne knows a random dial within a Rocket Launch Control Room will generate the correct sound through the speakers... but that's another point)

While it is not stated outright, by the fact that the symbiotic reacts exactly the same way to the plane as it does to all other instances of that sound frequency, it is therefore suggested that the plane generates that frequency.

Is this correct? i'm not sure and cannot find sound frequency ranges online for aircraft from the ground. plenty for while on-board though.

And more significant question might be why that plane was flying so low over that building!!!!